# How to add image component to tkinter GUI?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a relatively simple python script utilizing a tkinter GUI

the code looks something like

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()

def f1():
    print "function f1 does stuff, nice.."


title = Label(text="Tweet Grabber 1.1")
title.pack(fill=X)

b = Button(master, text="OK", command=f1)
b.pack(fill=X)

mainloop()
```

Using tkinter is it possible to add an image component?

ultimately where I can go something like `img = image(src="path/imagename.filetype")`

then `img.pack()`

also

Is it possible to use an image as a button with tkinter?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, you can use PIL (python imaging library), but it isn't necessary the below code should work:

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()

def f1():
    print "function f1 does stuff, nice.."

def imageclick():
    print 'you clicked the button, nice...'

image = PhotoImage(file = 'directory or name of file.gif (if image is in same folder as .py file)')

img_button = Button(image = image, command = imageclick)
img_button.pack()

title = Label(text="Tweet Grabber 1.1")
title.pack(fill=X)

b = Button(master, text="OK", command=f1)
b.pack(fill=X)

mainloop()
```

if this doesn't work get back to me, I haven't tested this on python 2.7 but it should work :), hope that helps you.

Comment: @L.Clarkson Edit was an alright addition, however it should have been a comment really ;)